# ReactJs StyledComponents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use one property for returning styled button. I am searching for something similar:

```
const Button = styled.button`
 /* Adapt the colors based on primary prop */
  background: ${props => props.primary ? 'palevioletred' : 'white'};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? 'white' : 'palevioletred'};

  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

export default Button;
```

Unfortunately i have more than 2 props based on which i need to return styled component.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass object as a property.

```
<Button myStyle={ { color: color ... } } />
```

you will be using them as

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props => props.myStyle && props.myStyle.color ? props.myStyle.color : 'somethingdefault'};
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for hint, I used function for determination which color to set.

```
     function getColor(props){
          if(props.btn==='red'){return 'red';}
      }    


     color: ${(props) => getColor(props)};
```

Comment: glad to help :)